# Why is this a topology on $Y$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $f$ be a continuous map from $X$ onto $Y$, and $f$ is a quotient map. Why is the family $\tau_q $ of all $f(U)$, where $U$ is open in $X$, a topology on $Y$?

Comment: I can't prove that $\tau _q$ is closed under finite intersection.

Comment: I am confused by the hypotheses. You say $f$ must be a cts map, which implies that $Y$ came with a topology. But this can't possibly be used anywhere, since we are only being asked to check that another collection of subsets of $Y$ forms a topology.

Comment: All sets $O$ that are open in the original topology on $Y$ (which must be assumed to exist or continuity of $f$ does not make any sense) are open under this definition, as for onto maps $O = f[f^{-1}[O]]$. Don't yet see how to use this yet.

Comment: Does change something if we suppose that $f$ is a quotient map? (I edited my original post)

Comment: Yes, so what does it mean for $f$ to be a quotient map?

Comment: It means that if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open then $U$ is open. But I still don't see why this implies that is a topology :(

Comment: Well, show us precisely where you're stuck when you use this hypothesis.

Comment: OK, I agree there's a problem. Are you sure there isn't an extra hypothesis, like $U=f^{-1}(f(U))$ for all these open sets?

Comment: I don't think so. I just think this problem is wrong. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 7):

It is not, in fact, a topology. For a simple counterexample, let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with the topology $\{ \{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, X, \emptyset\}$. Let $Y=\{1,2,3\}$ with the indiscrete topology. Define $f$ as $f(1)=1, f(2)=f(3)=2, f(4)=3$. Now, 
$$ \tau_q = \{ Y, \emptyset, \{1,2\}, \{2,3\}\}$$ which is not closed under intersection.

Edit: $f$ is also a quotient map.

Comment: We can suppose in addition that $f$ is a quotient map, just in case that it changes something... thank you